# typeahead it just returning letter by letter

Tags: codeigniter-3, bootstrap-typeahead, jquery-ajaxq

I want to make an autocomplete search box, when I try to realize an search it is returning me letter by letter instead of word by words. it also is returning me one value from db when I have two values. I am using typeahead.min.js from bootstrap. why is this happening?

controller

```
public function search(){
        $search = $this->input->post('search');
        $query  = $this->products->search($search);
        $data = array();
        foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
           $this->json($value);
        }
    }
```

model

```
public function search($data){
        $this->db->like('description',$data,'both');
        $query = $this->db->get('storelte_products');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

ajax

```
    $('#search').typeahead({
      source: function (query,process) {
        $.ajax({
            url: URL_SEARCH_PRODUCT,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {query: query},
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
              console.log(data);
              process(data.description);
            }
        });
      }
   });
```

[image: search_box]
json

```
{"id":"4165","provider_id":"1005","hash_id":"a7f0d2b95c60161b3f3c82f764b1d1c9","code":"BCBF-BE6A","description":"ajg","purchase_price":"7.00","sale_price":"77.00","wholesale_price":"7.00","min_stock":"7","stock":"7","max_stock":"7","created_at":"2017-04-09 22:21:28","status":"1"}
```

[image: table_Db]

Comment: It's correct, you've type `j` so it will query a description of `ajg`. The issue on the display, Have you tried `processAsnyc`?

Comment: yes , but not working